# How can I call a constructor after statements?

Tags: java, constructor

I have this calss KeywordFilter. I want the constrcutor that accepts a keyword to create a List, add the keyword to the list and then call the constructor with the list parameter. How can I do that? because as I know, calling the constructor should be the first call.

```
public class KeywordFilter implements Filter {

    private List<String> filteringKeywords;

    public KeywordFilter(List<String> filteringKeywords) {
        this.filteringKeywords = filteringKeywords;
    }

    public KeywordFilter(String keyword) {
        List<String> filteringKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        filteringKeywords.add(keyword);
        this(filteringKeywords);//This makes a compilation error
    }

}
```

Comment: `this(Arrays.asList(keyword));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can put the code that constructs the list in a separate function (preferably, but not necessarily, `static`):

```
private static List<String> makeFilterKeywords(String keyword) {
    List<String> filteringKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    filteringKeywords.add(keyword);
    return filteringKeywords;
}
public KeywordFilter(String keyword) {
    this(makeFilterKeywords(keyword));
}
```

Comment: You forgot to pass `keyword` as argument.

Comment: @TimB This is true, Java lets you do it. However, in general one shouldn't call instance functions before the constructor has finished.

Comment: @MariuszS Not really: had the question been "how can I construct a list inline", I would agree that my code is a little too much. However, given that OP asked to "run code before constructor", the most general solution is placing that code in a function, and calling it.

Comment: This is a general solution because I just decided to change to Set instead of List

Answer (score 5):

Create your list directly :

```
public KeywordFilter(String keyword) {
  this(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(keyword)));
}
```

Comment: `this(Arrays.asList(keyword));` is enough

Comment: @MariuszS Not if you want to add or remove some elements in the `filteringKeywords` list after it's construction. `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list.

Comment: But we don't want here :)

Comment: @MariuszS How do you know? May the OP wants to add some new keywords to the current list after it's construction. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
public KeywordFilter(String keyword) {
    this(Collections.singletonList(keyword));
}
```

Comment: yay! yet another useful method I can add to my toolkit! Hadn't seen singleton list before.

Comment: *Returns an immutable list containing only the specified object.*, without `add()` or `remove()`

Comment: @MariuszS yes, it's notable. Though it's a good practice to make everything immutable where it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public KeywordFilter(List<String> filteringKeywords) {
        this.filteringKeywords = filteringKeywords;
    }

    public KeywordFilter(String keyword) {
       this(((List<String>)Arrays.asList(keyword));
    }
```

Comment: Casting is not needed.

Comment: As asList return List I thought casting is required or else it will result in compilation error, as it does not know the type of object in list?

Comment: No! `public static <T> java.util.List<T> asList(T... a)`

Comment: Read @ZouZou answer, this returns *a fixed-size list backed by the specified array*, without `add()` or `remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

## The simplest and shorten solution

```
public KeywordFilter(String keyword) {
    this(Arrays.asList(keyword));
}
```

But this returns *a fixed-size list backed by the specified array*, without `add()` or `remove()` support.

This is applicable also to [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

```
public KeywordFilter(String...  keywords) {
    this(Arrays.asList(keywords));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `ArrayList` with the `KeyWord` and then have another method append the new list to existing list (which you have created with only the keyword in the constructor).

Something like this:

```
public class KeywordFilter implements Filter {

    private List<String> filteringKeywords;

    public KeywordFilter(String keyword) { //Consctructor
        filteringKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        filteringKeywords.add(keyword);
    }

   public void appendList(List<String> filteringKeywords) { //new method 
        filteringKeywords.addAll(filteringKeywords);
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean   filteringKeywords.addAll(filteringKeywords); ??

Comment: still that doesn't work, suppose I call the second constructor first, then it returns a null pointer exception.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted say addAll, of course. But @AlexTwain, are you sure this doesn't works? If you create a list in the constructor with 1 element (the keyword) and then you call the new method to append the new list to the existing list (which have only your keyword), it doesn't works?